# iOS Dev: NSArray for UITableView labels returning ' index 1 out of bounds '

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

Gday, trying to split my looping tableview array into it's own static array which is then used on each label in the UITableView...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ListingCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView
                         dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
            initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
            reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

//Load Row Value into NSArray
NSString *RowValues = [self.ListingArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
NSArray *RunTimeArray = [RowValues componentsSeparatedByString:@","];


//Configure the cell.
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [RunTimeArray objectAtIndex:1]; //small label
cell.textLabel.text = [RunTimeArray objectAtIndex:0]; //main title

return cell;
}
```

When I run the project, it returns an error:

```
DATE APP_NAME[28399:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
```

Basically this means Index :1 doesn't exist but Index:0 does... when I re-join the array with for instance '-------' it all shows right so its meaning the new object has a different Index to 1 or another consecutive number.

Any idea how to make them consecutive indexes like: 0,1,2,3,4 and not 0,21581,2185929,385749...

Thanks :)

Comment: What is "RowValues"?  And, when you NSLog it, how many entries in "RunTimeArray"?

Comment: BTW:  It's standard Objective-C coding convention to name variables with a leading lower-case letter, and reserve leading upper-case names for class names.

Comment: (An NSArray never has non-consecutive index values.)

Answer (score 0):

Verify the following things

1) The value returned in numberOfRowsInSection:  should be [self.listingArray count];

2) RunTimeArray count should always be >=2.