# '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

```
cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Empty" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Cell1" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:1];
```

I get an index beyond bounds error. I have tried to change the numbers but no luck!
Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have been googling and all of the solutions found online have been no help. Thanks.

.m

```
#import "SettingsViewController.h"
@interface SettingsViewController ()

@end

@implementation SettingsViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 2;
}
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView
                             dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Empty" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
        cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Cell1" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:1];

    }


    return cell;
}
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSString *sectionName;
    switch (section)
    {
        case 0:
            sectionName = NSLocalizedString(@"General", @"General");
            break;
        case 1:
            sectionName = NSLocalizedString(@"myOtherSectionName", @"myOtherSectionName");
            break;
            // ...
        default:
            sectionName = @"";
            break;
    }
    return sectionName;
}
#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    /*
     <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
     // ...
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
     */
}
@end
```

Comment: Try [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15914626/ios-dev-nsarray-for-uitableview-labels-returning-index-1-out-of-bounds).  You and user2264008 seem to be in the same class.

Comment: (Of course, the array index out of bounds is the least of your problems.)

Answer (score 0):

To load custom nib i am using,

make NSObject category class and added this code in it.

```
+ (id)loadNibNamed:(NSString *)NibName {
    NSObject *cl = nil;
    if (NSClassFromString(NibName) != nil) {
        NSArray *arr = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:NibName owner:self options:nil];
        for (id cls in arr) {
            if([cls isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(NibName)])
            {
                cl = cls;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cl;
}
```

And calling it like,

```
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = (UITableViewCell *)[[class class] loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass(class)];
    }
```

It will help you.